# Custom traceId from headers

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I'm using sleuth 3.1.8 and spring-boot 2.7.11

When I call my rest api from another spring application, traceId is propagated and printing correctly.

But when I try to call my rest api from postman passing below headers, sleuth is not considering them and generating its own traceId and spanId.

x-b3-traceid
x-b3-spanid
x-b3-parentspanid

Answer (score 0):

Usually instrumented apps share the 3 headers you mentionned plus this header `X-B3-Sampled = 1` (`value == 1` to report the trace or `value == 0` to deny the trace and not report it).

So your trace could be reported from Postman, add the `X-B3-Sampled` header with the value 1.